# meaning of the preposition "over" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the piece:

> A correct squat perfectly balances all the forces around the knees and the hips, using these muscles in exactly the way the skeletal biomechanics are designed for them to be used, **over** their full range of motion.

Comment: [across or spanning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/over#Preposition) - in this exercise, these muscles go to 100% of their capacity (fully extended/contracted) and back to their starting position. Accordingly, your legs go from standing to fully bended in the knees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preposition *over* is often used to mean *throughout* or *acting across.* Thus, "over their full range of motion" means that the muscles are using their full range, stretching from one end/extreme to the other.